# Crystal Reports and IIS 7 on Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, crystal-reports, windows-server-2008

A mate of mine has recently deployed a site of theirs to a Windows 2008 sp1 Server with IIS 7. The app itself runs fine with no problems, however when they try launch a Crystal Report they get a 404 error.

If they manually try access the path using the IP of the server instead of the server name the report loads fine though.

Can anyone point us in the right direction to sort this issue out? I would assume that there is a setting we missing in IIS 7 since this ran perfectly in IIS 6 on a 2003 server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got the issue pinpointed to SQL 2008 Reporting Services. It creates a virtual directory called Reports. This clashed with the site folder also called Reports.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727825/crystal-reports-images-not-visible-in-web-viewer/) I answered, where the problem had to do with the execute permissions on the special "CrystalReportViewers115" folder (exact folder name changes with the version of Crystal).  The solution in that case was to execute permissions on the folder to "scripts & executables".