# Crystal Report viewer not showing the embedded image

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports, .net-4.5, crystal-reports-viewer

Crystal Report viewer not showing the embedded image "the logo" of the report at the runtime, instead of an image i got a label with text "image" as you can see:
[image]

and this the original one in the design mode
[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Pro, asp.net 4.5, and Crystal Report 13 ver. 13.0.25.3158.

I have tried everything mentioned in this post:
[Crystal Reports images not visible in web viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727825/crystal-reports-images-not-visible-in-web-viewer)

here is  the handlers in my web.config:

```
    <httpHandlers>
                <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        </httpHandlers>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

the same problem in both my Dev laptop and the actual server.
Any suggestion please?

Comment: What image format did you use? Have you tried different format like JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP instead?

Comment: Yes I did tried different type of format, none of them did work.

Comment: Also, makes wonder if you can use an absolute URL and point it to an image host like imgur. I'm not clear where the image is located and if the report can find the image.

Comment: I'm using a bath located in the project folder, forgot to tell you that when I export the report to  PDF the image appears in the exported file!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the path in httpHandlers and in handlers section in web.config  from :

```
path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx"
```

to

```
path="CrystalImageHandler*"
```

in web.config :

```
    <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler*" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    </httpHandlers>


<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler*" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

</system.webServer>
```